# PowerShell export to CSV offset rows

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I updated some code from a something I found that exports multiple sheets from an Excel file to CSV files. I need to export without the first 6 rows. They all have the same format.

Where can I apply an offset for each tab?

```
function ExportWSToCSV {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$excelPath,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$excelFileName,
        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$excelFormat,
        [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$csvPath
    )

    Write-Output "Your cvs files are located " $csvPath

    $excelFile= $excelPath + $excelFileName + $excelFormat
    $E = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $E.Visible = $false
    $E.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $wb = $E.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
    foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets) {
        $n = $excelFileName + "_" + $ws.Name
        $ws.SaveAs($csvPath + $n + ".csv", 6)
    }
    $E.Quit()
}
```

Comment: Delete the first 6 rows from each sheet before exporting, then discard the changes before closing the workbook.

Comment: could you give me an example of this ? I would like to run it in all the same code. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in `Delete()` method. This is available to the [`EntireRow` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff836836(v=office.14).aspx), which is part of the [`Range` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel).

Change:

```
foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets) {
    $n = $excelFileName + "_" + $ws.Name
    $ws.SaveAs($csvPath + $n + ".csv", 6)
}
```

To:

```
foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets) {
    $ws.range("A1:A6").EntireRow.Delete()
    $n = $excelFileName + "_" + $ws.Name
    $ws.SaveAs($csvPath + $n + ".csv", 6)
}
```

Comment: Works great. I was looking at a different way which was convoluted
Thanks